# SQL query to combine tables (n:n)

Tags: php, mysql, join, phpmyadmin, left-join

I have these tables:

**CATEGORIES**:

1. id
2. name

**KIBE_TRAEGER**:

1. id
2. name

**COUNTIES**:

1. id
2. region_id
3. country_id
4. county_code
5. county_de

**REGIONS**:

1. id
2. country
3. region_de

**CONTACTS**:

1. id
2. firstname
3. surname
4. company
5. zipcode
6. city
7. region --> =regions.id --> should show regions.region_de
8. county --> =counties.id --> should show counties.county_de
9. tel1
10. tel2
11. mobile
12. fax
13. email1
14. email2
15. homepage
16. categories --> =categories.id **BUT** in table "contacts" it's written
        with ;catnr; (e.g. an entry can have more than 1 entry:
        ";6;;7;;8;;16;") --> should show categories.name
17. notes
18. active
19. pernr

**KIBE_CONTACTS**:

1. id
2. openinghours
3. costs
4. groups
5. handicapplaces
6. freeplaces
7. traeger --> =kibe_traeger.id same as categories ;traegerId; (e.g.";1;;5;") --> should show kibe_traeger.name

and I want to combine all of them to export it to csv.

Btw. i tried my poor queries so far directly in phpmyadmin with left join and inner join but I'm relly poor in SQL stuff and wont learn it anymore :P ...

My code so far (edited according to Matt Cremeen's answers):

Working:

```
SELECT 
    contacts.id, contacts.firstname, contacts.surname, contacts.company, 
    contacts.zipcode, contacts.city, contacts.country, contacts.region,
    contacts.county, contacts.tel1, contacts.tel2, contacts.mobile, 
    contacts.fax, contacts.email1, contacts.email2, contacts.homepage,
    contacts.active, contacts.pernr, kibe_contacts.id as contacts_id, 
    kibe_contacts.openinghours, kibe_contacts.costs, kibe_contacts.groups,
    kibe_contacts.handicapplaces, kibe_contacts.freeplaces, 
    kibe_contacts.traeger, kibe_traeger.id as traeger_id, kibe_traeger.name,
    counties.id as counties_id, counties.region_id as region_id, 
    counties.country_id as country_id, counties.county_code, counties.county_de,
    regions.id as regions_id, regions.country as regions_country, regions.region_de
FROM
    contacts
INNER JOIN
    kibe_contacts ON contacts.id = kibe_contacts.contact_id
INNER JOIN
    regions ON contacts.region = regions.id
INNER JOIN
    counties ON contacts.county = counties.id
```

**Not** working:

```
INNER JOIN
    kibe_traeger ON kibe_contacts.traeger = kibe_traeger.id
INNER JOIN
    categories ON contacts.categories = categories.id;
```

I'm getting a "Null-Result" I think I know why I get this error: because in the column `kibe_contacts.traeger` and `contacts.categories` there are more than one values which are separated with `;` e.g. an entry can have more than 1 entry: `;6;;7;;8;;16;` but in categories.id there is always just a single id e.g. 4.

Is there any solution to query this out?

**Last Edit**: Solved the second problem by myself: i exported the list and did it with search & replace.

Thanks again to all the helpers!

Comment: the "..." part is where you need to connect your tables like `... where contacts.countries=countries.id, ...`

Comment: thank you for the quick response... i know, but i dont know exactly how. i already tried with innerjoin and leftjoin but it seems like i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: i can also post the code i already tried but i dont think thats very helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `id` field corresponds to each table, you are going to want to join each table on that field. I won't write all of the code here, but it'll start like this

```
SELECT contacts.id, contacts.firstname, contacts.surname, ...
FROM contacts
INNER JOIN
kibe_contacts
ON contacts.id = kibe_contacts.id
INNER JOIN
regions
on contacts.region_id = regions.id
...
```

Comment: Thank you! That looks good - i will try it out tomorrow - enough for today :)

Comment: Hello, i think i've done something wrong.. i added the adapted code from you in my post above. It throws the following error:

Comment: After looking at your edits @Niko I'm not sure if your problem is resolved or not. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

try to use `GROUP_CONCAT` function of MySQL. Here my sample SQL

I've 2 tables, `clientes ('Id' int, 'nome' varchar(50) )`

```
clientes
1 Rafael
2 Jony
3 Smith
```

and `clientes_devices ('Id' int, 'id_cliente' int, 'device' varchar(50) )`

```
clientes_devices 
1 1 AsusZenFone
2 1 MotorolaG
3 2 WindowsPhone
```

Here is the select command

```
select c.nome, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT d.device SEPARATOR ',') AS Device
from clientes c
join clientes_dispositivos d on (c.id = d.id_cliente)
where c.id = 1
```

this is the output

[image: SQL Output with the Group_Concat function]

 Without the function, I got this

[image: Without the function, I got this]